# How to set pagetheme according to user

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, themes

I want my webpage to have some theme options which will be decided according to choice of the user. As far as I know, I should set `Page.Theme` in the `OnPreInit` event. However, in that event I cannot reach the user's logonName. Now I am using a table to record the users' choice. Should I use cookie or do you have any idea for my problem?

Comment: you can use cookie and reset while user change theme.can you explain more detail like you need theme before login as well ? or only for after login ?

Comment: Actually I had started using cookies but I had face with the problem that some browsers do not allow to me use their cookies do you have any recommandation for this? I am planning that I will show the default theme when page load after the user logged in, I will reset theme.

Comment: store theme value in session or data caching  and apply it.

Comment: If I use session how will I reach the theme choice after some time have passed? User may enter the website few times in a week or day.

Comment: as u say u store in table to record the user;'s choice then get the theme value at the time of session n apply got it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `PreInit` event of each page you should say that :

```
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.GlobalTheme = <ThemeName>
```

ThemeName is the name of the Theme (string)

Comment: Thx for the reply but my problem is that I set the  ThemeName according to logonName but I cannot reach logonName in the PreInit event.

Comment: use a global theme for login and after login you can change it.. Use session to save the theme name..